# Tomcat Connector Matching Property Warning

Tags: java, security, tomcat, ssl, ssl-certificate

I am trying to configure tomcat to handle connections using SSL, giving a keystore with the certificate of the server and a truststore for the client certificates to trust. The connector configuration looks like below:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
    maxThreads="200"
    SSLEnabled="true"
    scheme="https"
    secure="true"
    keystoreFile="/server_certs/webserver_certificate.p12"
    keystorePass="password"
    keystoreType="pkcs12"
    trustoreFile="/server_cert/truststore_dev.jks"
    trustorePass="changeit"
    trustoreType="jks"
    clientAuth="true"
    sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

The problem with the above is that i am getting the following WARNINGS in the logs:

**"WARNING: [SetAllPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Connector} Setting property 'trus
toreFile' to 'C:\Apps\apache\apache-tomcat-7.0.41\server_certs\truststore_dev.jk
s' did not find a matching property."**

Which i guess means that the truststore is not taken into consideration. When i am trying to access a web page, it complains that the client does not have any certificates that the server requires.

Is there anything wrong i am doing? I thought the **trustoreFile**, **truststorePass** and **truststoreType** are common properties of the Connector.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have misspelled some of the attribute names.  For example, there is no `"trustoreFile"` attribute ... but there is a `"truststoreFile"` attribute.

See http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html#SSL_Support for the correct spellings.

Comment: Thank you so much Stephen C. You are 100% right. Cannot believe this cost me half a day. Thank you again.